# HTML search image src who starts with a*.jpg

Tags: html

I will like to know if there is any way to get and image in html with the following syntax:

```
<img src="images/tow*.jpg" alt="">
```

where we will find the only image who starts with "tow" like "tower" without needing to write the whole name of the image.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use a server side language such as PHP to look through files in a directory and use regex to return a list of matches. HTML on it's own can't do that since it doesn't have a way to query files on a server.

Answer (score 2):

Not within `html`. Those image tag `src` attributes must be concrete paths to images; however, you can use scripts to dynamically find and attach images like what you want.